# `git blame/annotate`: terminate on merge commits

Tags: git

There is some debate amongst team members:

1. Some people love to see pull requests squashed before merge
2. Some people love to be able to see the commit history of how a feature was developed.

As somebody who leans towards the second camp I view the first camp's main objection centered around `git blame` / `git annotate` showing the commit where the change was made as distinct to the commit where the change was introduced to the current branch.

I cannot find any command line options on `git blame` / `git annotate` that would have it stop at merge to current branch.

This question can be resolved with an answer to the following: Is there some secondary command I am missing or is this a feature request I need to file?

(Update: co-workers also complain that visualizing history with many PRs is a pain but I believe there are flags to gitk, etc that address that problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I admittedly lean towards the second camp myself, I am not aware of any options to achieve that with `git annotate`.

So to answer your question, you may need to file a feature request. However I suspect it wouldn't be accepted given that according to [the docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-annotate),

> this command exists only for backward compatibility to support
>   existing scripts, and provide a more familiar command name for people
>   coming from other SCM systems.

Comment: I am not seeing the feature in `git blame` either. I don't mind whether it's only in `annotate` or `blame` as long as the feature exists... not seeing the option in `git blame` though

Comment: @StephenConnolly I wasn't implying that `git blame` does have the feature, but, yes, I agree I don't think it has it either. Just a thought and not exactly what you're after, but wouldn't `-L <start>,<end>` do?

Comment: See https://github.com/git/git/commit/7580f6b122e68c0ce4939c6a67e7f8f06e756fc6 this feature is being added to `git blame`

Comment: @StephenConnolly nice one :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a command chain that gives the desired output:

```
git rev-list --first-parent HEAD | awk '{print p " " $0}{p=$0}' > tmpfile && \
 git blame -b -S tmpfile HEAD -- path && rm tmpfile
```

I have also submitted a [feature request](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/277658) to the git project... we'll see how that goes

Comment: The fix for `git blame --first-parent` is en route to master: https://github.com/git/git/commit/7580f6b122e68c0ce4939c6a67e7f8f06e756fc6

Comment: That fix seems now combined with `--reverse`. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33592585/6309)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the fix [requested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32521749/6309) by [Stephen Connolly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1589700/stephen-connolly), combining first-parent with reverse should land in Git 2.7 (Nov/Dev 2015).

See [commit 700fd28](https://github.com/git/git/commit/700fd28e4f3ecd6e7b5f8f2098e62ffef9ab958b), [commit 1b0d400](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b0d40000a511a8db81a20a6dab00984bdbc0d63), [commit ec35240](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ec352401fb7f74939cbd1154a878e094f75d79ce) (30 Oct 2015) by [Max Kirillov (`max630`)](https://github.com/max630).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6784eb5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6784eb5ad93da15d24a5d111a3d6df618f98532f), 03 Nov 2015)</sup>

> ## `blame`: allow `blame --reverse --first-parent` when it makes sense

> Allow combining `--reverse` and `--first-parent` if initial commit of
> specified range is at the first-parent chain starting from the final
> commit.

---

The long explanation is:

> **Reverse blame can be used to locate removal of lines which does not change adjacent lines**. Such edits do not appear in non-reverse blame, because the adjacent lines last changed commit is older history, before the edit.

> For a big and active project which uses topic branches, or analogous feature, for example pull-requests, **the history can contain many concurrent branches**, and even after an edit merged into the target branch, there are still many (sometimes several tens or even hundreds) topic branch which do not contain it:

```
 a0--a1-----*a2-*a3-a4...-*a100
 |\         /   /         /
 | b0-B1..bN   /         /
 |\           /         /
 | c0..   ..cN         /
 \                    /
  z0..            ..zN
```

> Here, the '`*`'s mark the first parent in merge, and uppercase `B1` - the
> commit where the line being blamed for was removed.
> Since commits `cN-zN` do not contain `B1`, they still have the line removed in `B1`, and reverse blame can report that the last commit for the line was `zN` (meaning that it was removed in `a100`). In fact it really does return
> some very late commit, and **this makes it unusable for finding the `B1` commit**.

> The search could be done by `blame --reverse --first-parent`.
> For range `a0..a100` it would return a1, and then only one additional blame along the `a0..bN` will return the desired commit `b0`.
> But combining `--reverse` and `--first-parent` was forbidden in [95a4fb0 (Git 2.6.2)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/95a4fb0eac20de024fed242a7c9227af86334202), because incorrectly specified range could produce unexpected and meaningless result.

The test goal is to find A1:

> Creates the history shown below.
> '`*`'s mark the first parent in the merges.
> The only line of `file.t` is changed in commit `B2`

```
        +---C1
       /      \
 A0--A1--*A2--*A3
   \     /
    B1-B2
```

---

The "[`git blame --first-parent`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5707ac426d3ab3b2f8c4074b6af6f8a4646236ce/Documentation/blame-options.txt#L39)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame#Documentation/git-blame.txt---first-parent))</sup> option was not documented, but now it is with Git 2.29 (Q4 2020).

See [commit 11bc12a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/11bc12ae1ecf78fe445c12e53455f981299d708d) (06 Aug 2020) by [Raymond E. Pasco (`juped`)](https://github.com/juped).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5707ac4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5707ac426d3ab3b2f8c4074b6af6f8a4646236ce), 13 Aug 2020)</sup>

> ### [`blame-options.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/11bc12ae1ecf78fe445c12e53455f981299d708d): document `--first-parent` option
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Raymond E. Pasco</sup>

> `blame`/`annotate` have supported `--first-parent` since [commit 95a4fb0eac](https://github.com/git/git/commit/95a4fb0eac20de024fed242a7c9227af86334202) ("`blame`: handle `--first-parent`"). This adds a blurb on that option to the documentation.

`blame-options` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/11bc12ae1ecf78fe445c12e53455f981299d708d/Documentation/blame-options.txt#L39-L44):

> ### `--first-parent`
>
> Follow only the first parent commit upon seeing a merge
> commit.
> This option can be used to determine when a line
> was introduced to a particular integration branch, rather
> than when it was introduced to the history overall.